# Error with pngquant when php artisan nova:tool

Tags: npm, laravel-nova, pngquant

I'm using Laravel Nova. So, today I have been stuck with an error.

After running this command `php artisan nova:tool vendor/name`.
I got a prompt:
`Would you like to install the tool's NPM dependencies? (yes/no) [yes]`.

After "yes", npm started working, and I got an error with **pngquant**:

Also, **libpng-dev** **installed.**

```
✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

> pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall /var/www/project/nova-components/name/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

⚠ The `/var/www/project/nova-components/name/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
ℹ compiling from source
✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
at Promise.all.then.arr (/var/www/project/nova-components/name/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2021-05-10T16_02_15_536Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? Stuck on same issue now...